# java.security.Keystore aliases on JDK 1.6 vs IBM 1.5

Tags: java, security, openssl, keystore, java-6

I've a problem with the enum return value of KeyStore.aliases();

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/tmp/file.p12");
List<String> aliases = new ArrayList<String>();

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
is.close();

Enumeration<String> e=keystore.aliases();
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    // never reaches here because "e" is empty
    System.out.println(e.nextElement().toString());
    i++;
}
```

With
Java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

I get an empty enumerator

With
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pxi32devifx-20100511a (SR11 FP2 ))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Linux x86-32 j9vmxi3223ifx-20100510 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20100509_57823_lHdSMr
JIT  - 20091016_1845ifx7_r8
GC   - 20091026_AA)
JCL  - 20100511a

I am able to get all the aliases.

How can I retrieve all the store pkcs12 aliases with Sun/Oracle JDK6?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I'm aware, keystores are not binary compatible accross different JVM implementations. (i.e. SUN java vs IBM Java). I don't think it's related to 1.5 vs 1.6

Comment: Which SecurityProvider was providing the store (`Keystore.getProvider()`) in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code to me, and I'd have thought that PKCS#12 keystores should be readable across all versions of all JREs.

Have you tried using OpenSSL to verify your store?

Comment: > openssl pkcs12 -in /tmp/file.p12 -nokeys -nocerts -info
Enter Import Password:
MAC Iteration 1
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: (chg by me)***************, Iteration 1
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Key bag
Certificate bag
keytool -list -v -keystore /tmp/file.p12 
keytool error (likely untranslated): java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
It works with openssl, but don't work with keytool java based tool

Comment: Seems like sun jdk 1.6 can't access to this p12 file format. But actually I'd thought PKCS12 was a generic file format to prevent compatibility issues between keystores formats.

Comment: If it couldn't access PKCS#12 stores, you'd get an exception when you call getInstance("PKCS12"), so it is supported, but it's a bit fussy.  Can you create a keystore with Sun, and open with OpenSSL and IBM?

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ77005

--
Problem conclusion
This defect will be fixed in:
1.4.2 SR14
5.0.0 SR12
6.0.0 SR9

The `PKCS SafeContents.getSafeBags( )` method was modified to detect when the SafeBag array is null and to return an empty SafeBag array instead.  PKCS callers of this method are prepared to handle an empty SafeBag array.